# android Image resize in listview

Tags: android, resize, imageview

I've got an ImageView in a relative layout both with following properties android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"

[image]

I fill this layout in a ListItem within a mainactivity with the help of an Adapter. Then I try to resize in Adapter with the code below;

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics(); dm = ctx .getResources().getDisplayMetrics(); int width = dm.widthPixels; int height = width * 243 / 325;

          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height); thumbImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

But the images get stuck in the listview item even smaller than their original size.

xml that contains imageview that is filled in Adapter is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <relativelayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" android:padding="0dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvKategori"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivThumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

</relativelayout>
```

And this is the mainactivity xml that has the listview and I fill lvGununVideolari listview and lvEnCokIzlenenler content.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.drawerlayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

/>

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"/>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="0px"
android:paddingLeft="0px"
android:paddingRight="0px"
android:paddingTop="0px" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="0px"
    android:paddingLeft="0px"
    android:paddingRight="0px"
    android:paddingTop="0px"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGununVideolari"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:text="Günün Videoları"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEnCokIzlenenler"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:text="En Çok İzlenenler"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvGununVideolari"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="0px"
        android:paddingLeft="0px"
        android:paddingRight="0px"
        android:paddingTop="0px" >
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvEnCokIzlenenler"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingBottom="0px"
        android:paddingLeft="0px"
        android:paddingRight="0px"
        android:paddingTop="0px" >

    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>

</linearlayout> </android.support.v4.widget.drawerlayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to setup the way Image should be scaled, like:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivThumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
```

And there are other options available for `scaleType`.
But thats not all, also to do autoresize you need to setup particular size of `ImageView` like:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivThumbnail"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
```

however you do mostly the same in code via LayoutParams :)

Comment: it doesnt work, is there a spesific height size for item in listview. this is new screetshot for fitxy : https://www.dropbox.com/s/274s2fe59cc1pvr/Screenshot%20from%202014-02-06%2000%3A45%3A02.png

Comment: Actually it works as expected. the only problem is the width. try to comment your code with LayoutParams and set up 50dp width and height like in my 2nd part. Also try to set android:adjustViewBounds="true". As you can see on your screenshot all images are of same height and same width but the width is too big.

Comment: I deleted the layout params code in adapter. here the screen shot : https://www.dropbox.com/s/kzpf5kv999wspa2/Screenshot%20from%202014-02-06%2000%3A57%3A56.png

Comment: yes, once again everything is fine and works as expected. Your question is about resizing and you got it. You wrote in your question - But the images get stuck in the listview item even smaller than their original size. Now images are not smaller or bigger - they all are of same dimensions. And like I said "there are other options available" for scaling way. Try other options and lern how it works.

Comment: ops I found the problem : android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"